# CSS Modules, Composition in nested class

Tags: sass, css-modules

I am working on a project where there is a main style.scss file for a number of components. I want to restructure the code so as every component has its own folder (index.js, styles.scss). There is a nested class that is using a class from another component and now that I have to separate all the styles, this part is broken. I can't use composition since it is a nested class. What other approaches can I take?

The code looks like this:

```
// Component A styless.scss

.component-a-class {

}

// Component B styless.scss 

.component-b-class{

.component-a-class {

  }
}
```

Comment: Try watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTBaQ2DcGUk

Answer (score 0):

Use Sass's [`@import`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) directive to import the external classes. Your code would become something like this:

```
// ComponentA/styless.scss

.component-a-class {
  ...
}

// ComponentB/styless.scss 

.component-b-class{
    @import "../ComponentA/styless.scss"
}
```

This will inject `.component-a-class` into the `.component-b-class` as a nested rule.

---

**Edit:** To import a style and also be able to modify one of its properties' values, you have to make use of Sass [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6):

```
// ComponentA/styless.scss

@mixin component-a-class($width: 100) {
    .component-a-class {
        width: $width + px;
    }
}

@include component-a-class();

// ComponentB/styless.scss

@import "../ComponentA/style.scss";

.component-b-class{
    @include component-a-class(500);
}
```

This will get you what you want, though it isn't ideal. The resulting compiled `ComponentB/styless.css` file will include *everything* written in `ComponentA/styless.scss` because the `@import` directive is an "all-or-nothing" feature (there is no selective import). The result would look like this:

```
// ComponentB/styless.css (compiled)

.component-a-class {
  width: 100px;
}

.component-b-class .component-a-class {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I forgot to mention that I also want to change the width of the whole component-a-class from component-b-class

Comment: Updated to include further clarification.